# C# SWIG vector<string> to string[]

Tags: c#, c++, swig

Given C++ methods like

```
std::vector< std::string > getFoo();
void setFoo( const std::vector< std::string > &foo);
```

How can I get SWIG to expose it like this to C#

```
string[] getFoo();
setFoo(string[] foo);
```

I realize that lots of [people have asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752983/89218) about `vector<string>` and SWIG, but I haven't seen anything addressing the conversion to/from `string[]`.  Everyone mentions using the SWIG templates, like this

```
%template(StringVector) vector<string>;
```

But that just creates a datatype that callers will have to know to marshal manually.  Ideally, a caller would only have to deal with `string[]` and let the SWIG layer figure it out.

How can I simply use `string[]` in C# but have it turn into `vector<string>` in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be to add [implicit casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to the SWIG-generated StringVector, so that it would be able to cast itself to/from `string[]`.

I tried doing this via a `typemap`, but couldn't make it work.  However, it can be done with [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It looks something like this.  In SWIG,

```
%include std_vector.i
%include std_string.i

/* allow partial c# classes */
%typemap(csclassmodifiers) SWIGTYPE "public partial class"

/* generate template around vector<string> */
%template(StringVector) std::vector< std::string >;
```

Then in C#, create a partial version of StringVector:

```
public partial class StringVector: IDisposable, System.Collections.IEnumerable
#if !SWIG_DOTNET_1
    , System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>
#endif
{
    // cast from C# string array
    public static implicit operator StringVector(string[] inVal) {
        var outVal= new StringVector();
        foreach (string element in inVal) {
            outVal.Add(element);
        }
        return outVal;
    }

    // cast to C# string array
    public static implicit operator string[](StringVector inVal) {
        var outVal= new string[inVal.Count];
        inVal.CopyTo(outVal);
        return outVal;
    }
}
```

This allows you to write C# code that looks like this:

```
string[] foo= mymodule.getFoo();
string[] thenewfoo= { "one", "two", "three" };
mymodule.setFoo(thenewfoo);
```

It's still StringVector in the C# method signatures, but since the client coder can just use `string[]` it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I feel that this is sacrificing quite a bit of efficiency for the sake of interface compatibility. Then again, I'd probably come up with the same idea in a pinch. +1

Comment: I figure most of the time people using the SWIG interface are really going to want `string[]`, so they'd be converting it manually anyway.  At any rate, one benefit of this approach is that you *could* use the StringVector directly if efficiency mattered.

Comment: Also, note that this will indeed work compiletime only. You can't pass the StringVector to any generic method and still expect it to do the userdefined conversion (there's no generic type constraint for that). Although, C#4.0' `dynamic` might be able to pull it off (need to check).

Comment: Any chance you could use `inval.ToArray()` instead? I mean, for .NET 3.5+ it could eliminate the copying in common cases.

Comment: The StringVector that SWIG generates only implements `IEnumerable`/`IList`, which don't seem to have a `ToArray` method.

Comment: @paleozogt Its a shot in the dark that anyone will see it... but here I go : Is there any way to keep the C# partial class definition in the interface file itself? I know that I can extend a wrapped C++ class, but I am not able to do that for the generated StringVector.

Comment: And can we keep the StringVector class internal?

Comment: It would be better to see `IList<string>` in the method signature instead of `StringVector`.