# Swig: pass std::vector<unsigned char> to c# function generated from c++

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I have a C++ function:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> foo(const std::vector<unsigned char>& v);
```

Swig generates the following C# function:

```
MapStringString foo(SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t v);
```

I want to call it inside C# function which receives byte[] and returns IDictionary, i.e.:

```
IDictionary<string, string> bar(byte[] b)
{
  SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t b1;

  // initialize b1 from b

  MapStringString m = foo(b1);

  IDictionary<string, string> result;

  // Populate result from MapStringString

  return result;
}
```

How do I initialize b1 from b (i.e. SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t from byte[]) and how to populate IDictionary from MapStringString?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know swig, but IntelliSense in Visual Studio, or Visual Studio's object browser (right-click on the type name, select "Go to definition" from the context menu) should be able to tell you which methods/fields/properties/indexers are provided by that swig-generated `SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t` and `MapStringString` types. I hope it shouldn't be too difficult once you actually see/know the methods/fields/properties/indexers  provided by those types...

Comment: Thanks! SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t in Visual Studio shows to me 4 methods: Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString - none of them looks suitable to extract elements of the array.

Comment: Is `SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t` perhaps deriving from a base class that might offer more helpful members?

Comment: No, it is not deriving from any class. It is actually a generated class. Everywhere in the internet Swig help shows how to generate classes, but nowhere how to use them.

Comment: Well, unless somebody can help you with swig (as i said, i don't know swig; i don't even know if and how swig would be capable of marshalling complex C++ types, which would be quite the feat). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) If nobody else can help, i would suggest you either change your C++ function signature to only use C data types (no C++ stuff, the function not being a C++ class member, either), or if that is not really suitable, write a C++/CLI assembly. In C++/CLI, you can mix C++ and managed .NET data types, allowing you to relatively comfortably write managed classes with methods that can convert between native C++ data types and managed data types. Basically, your C++/CLI assembly would use/interface with the C++ code, whereas your C# program would use this C++/CLI assembly like any normal assembly

Comment: Maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15147026 they discuss vector of string in that article, but maybe could be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can get started quickly with something like this in your SWIG interface:

```
%include <std_vector.i>
%template(VectorUChar) std::vector<unsigned char>;
```

That should give you a real type that you can work with from within C# that's a proxy to a C++ std::vector. (It'd work for your `bar()` function for example, but hardly be seamless at the point of call).

Since you've actually got a `Byte[]` already you could probably put together a typemap that transparently constructs a vector from a pointer + length if that's more useful.

Comment: Thank you! I was mislead that swig generated SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_unsigned_char_t by default and that type does not have any functionality. Now I realized that I should have added %template(VectorUChar) std::vector<unsigned char>; and that would generate a much better type instead of the default one and that type would have all required functionality.

Comment: No worries - normally if you see types like SWIGTYPE_ it's a sign that something hasn't been wrapped well automatically and worth investigating why.

Comment: @Flexo, Thank you. The above information helped me also. But I was trying to wrap C++ list to C# with this method and it failed. Can you please give help me in this situation? I am blocked here(trying to wrap List).

Comment: If it's a list then you'll need std_list.i instead then